# Matlab MCR append environment variable

Tags: linux, matlab, shell, unix, environment-variables

I'm not a linux expert, and before I may do some error, I would like to understand how to set my environment variables. After Matlavb MCR installation, I received this message:

```
On the target computer, append the following to your LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable:

/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/runtime/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/sys/os/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64/native_threads:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64


Next, set the XAPPLRESDIR environment variable to the following value:

/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/X11/app-defaults
```

I have a Red Hat server and I read about export command or

> add a file in /etc/ld.so.conf.d/ (it should end in .conf), containing
>   the full path of the directory

What is the best practice to permanently add this path to my environment variable?Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `.bashrc` file (or the corresponding resource file if you use a different shell), put the following code:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/runtime/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/sys/os/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64/native_threads:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64

export XAPPLRESDIR=/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/X11/app-defaults
```

NOTE: the syntax may be slightly different if you use a different shell.

Comment: Is it the best way? I read #It's NOT a good idea to change this file unless you know what you
# are doing. It's much better to create a custom.sh shell script in
# /etc/profile.d/ to make custom changes to your environment, as this
# will prevent the need for merging in future updates.

Comment: are you trying to make the change for every user, or just yourself?

Comment: I need to use MCR from my java code on tomcat server

Comment: You are going to have to update your paths when you update to future MATLAB versions anyway...I'm not sure that you gain anything by trying to avoid that.

Comment: I think setting the XAPPLRESDIR in your .bashrc is fine...you probably should be careful with the LD_LIBRARY_PATH...I thought you were setting this in a user profile.  That's why I put the reference to the existing $LD_LIBRARY_PATH in the export...that way you don't overwrite the existing LD_LIBRARY_PATH.